# How do I prevent selection scrolling in the body

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I have divs that are placed off-screen.

I have disabled scrollbars like so:

```
body {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Currently, when I highlight text and drag the mouse outside the window, the body still scrolls.

How can I prevent this behaviour?  (Setting offscreen elements to display: none is not an option.)

Thanks!

Travis

Comment: I'd like to know the answer to this too

Answer (score 0):

What browser is this happening in?

Where, off-screen, are the divs positioned? If they are off to the left or right, you could try using a negative top margin instead, as users are unlikely to highlight "up".